# VBA - Save Content of Range into file

Tags: excel, vba

I intent to download a range of a cells into a downloadable text-file. I need a piece of VBA-Code how to do this

I have a worksheet called "GPX". In this sheet there is geo-information available I want to download as text-file. But the code I use does format the text. But I do not want any formats.

```
A1: NAME OF GPX
A2: <gpx><trk><trkseg>
A3: <trkpt lat="49.927924" lon="8.475697"></trkpt>
A4: <trkpt lat="49.92792" lon="8.475716"></trkpt>
A5: </trkseg></trk></gpx>
```

I have tried this but it does add "" into the lines...

```
Dim myCSVFileName As String
Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim tempWB As Workbook
Dim rngToSave As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo err

Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
myCSVFileName = "meineroute.gpx"
mx = Sheets("GPX").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows.Row
Set rngToSave = Sheets("GPX").Range("A1:A" & mx)
rngToSave.Copy

Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With tempWB
    .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .SaveAs Filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close
End With
```

The result looks like this.

```
"<trkpt lat=""50.118418"" lon=""8.961555""></trkpt>"
"<trkpt lat=""50.118346"" lon=""8.961679""></trkpt>"
"<trkpt lat=""50.118263"" lon=""8.961781""></trkpt>"
```

But it has to be...

```
<trkpt lat="50.118418" lon="8.961555"></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="50.118346" lon="8.961679"></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="50.118263" lon="8.961781"></trkpt>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to paste code when I add a comment. I have been tried backtickets ``...but it does not work

Comment: I have put the code I use above....but I need a gpx file and this code does put "" into the lines

Comment: See my edits above.....this should emphasize what my problem is

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20060302021412/http:/www.dicks-blog.com:80/archives/2004/11/09/roll-your-own-csv/) on how to create your own text file. You just need to remove the code in the example where the author is comparing values (everything to do with the `vaColPad` array).